# C++ error when using array of void pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I want to have in `GameObject` class a vector of objects that inherits from `A` class, and a template method, that will add new objects of template type to the vector.

But I want to have possibility of using constructors, with parameters of unknown type, so I want to use void pointers array to do that, but I have an error saying:

> exited with non-zero status

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:

    virtual void whatever() { std::cout << "okay\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    float a;
    std::string b;
    int c;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "a,b,c values: " << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
    }

    B(void * parameters[])
    {
        this->a = *(static_cast<float*>(parameters[0]));   
        this->b = *(static_cast<std::string*>(parameters[0]));
        this->c = *(static_cast<int*>(parameters[0]));
    }
};

class GameObject
{
public:
    std::vector<A*> components{};

    template<class T>
    void AddComponent(void * parameters[])
    {
        auto t = new T(parameters);
        components.push_back(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    float f = 2524.218f;
    std::string s = "str";
    int i = 4214;

    auto g = new GameObject;

    void* ptr[3];

    ptr[0] = &f;
    ptr[1] = &s;
    ptr[2] = &i;

    g->AddComponent<B>(ptr);
    static_cast<B*>(g->components[0])->print();
}
```

Can you tell me what the problem is and if it's possible, correct the code?

Comment: Did you really mean to assign the same array entry to 3 different variables? This seems like a terrible design choice.

Comment: `parameters[0]` can't be a pointer to a `float`, a pointer to an `int` and a pointer to `std::string` at the same time. Think about what attempting to dereference it as a string when it's not a string will do. And learn about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    this->a = *(static_cast<float*>(parameters[0]));   
    this->b = *(static_cast<std::string*>(parameters[0]));
    this->c = *(static_cast<int*>(parameters[0]));
```

Did you mean:

```
    this->a = *(static_cast<float*>(parameters[0]));   
    this->b = *(static_cast<std::string*>(parameters[1]));
    this->c = *(static_cast<int*>(parameters[2]));
```

I.e. use different array indices.